# Display HTML Element Across Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I currently have a timer set up on an “admin” page with JavaScript and I want to display that same live clock on the homepage of my website. How can I do this? It’s basically two input fields that display number values. One displays minutes and one displays seconds. The values are updated using buttons which are found on the admin page. What I’m trying to do is display the current time that the clock is showing on the admin page on a separate page. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Copy the code over to the other page?  What do you have in mind?

Comment: Depending on a lot of factors you don't mention, you might try cookies, parameters to the homepage, or a common frame / page with home and admin being dynamically loaded, but we can't know what you deem "simple" and what really suits you. Also, this question is too broad for this website.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the value of the timer server side and just query it each second to see at what time it currently is. 
You could also use [socket.IO](http://socket.io/) to have real time access to the server timer.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. website is connectionless.

You can't push any event to other client page
without client behavior(like button click..)